# How can I integrate the Google Translate API with Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-translate

I am new to `Codeigniter`. How can I integrate the Google translate API with `Codeigniter`.

Can Google translator API only translate 5000 character at a time?

Comment: see [this](https://github.com/Stichoza/google-translate-php)

Comment: Anyway you have two questions in your question, "how to integerate API" and "is api only able to translate 5000 character at a time", I suggest you move one of them into a separate question